# troubles with fadeIn()/fadeOut(); jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, eventtrigger

got button named 'notebutt' vith 'oncklick' func

function is very simple user click's on button and div is fadeIn(), click again and div must fadeout();

```
        notebutt.bind("click", function () {
        var notediv = $(this).parent().find("div.notediv");
        // checking is notediv exist already, if not, creating one and do fadeIn(150);
        if (!notediv) {
        notediv = $('<div class="notediv" contenteditable="true"></div>');
        notediv.appendTo($(this).parent());
        notediv.offset({top: posT-47}).fadeIn(150);
        } else {
        // if got notediv created before, i must show or hide it with hideorshow(notediv);
                hideorshow(notediv);
        }

});
    // func that check's is div was showned or not
function hideorshow(div){
if ($(div).is(':visible')) {
    //hide if visible
    div.fadeOut();
} else {
        div.offset({top: posT-47});
        div.fadeIn();
}
};
```

at first sight it works like should, but after 5 - 10 clicks on button all goes wrong, 
div is randomly blink on click like if fadeIn and fadeOut runs in same time, or each other
is there is any way to make some proper trigger to check div state?

Comment: use toggle() - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: i need some thing like var status = 0;

Comment: to use later like if (status == 1) { do something and hide div} else { do other things} but i cant figure out how make this works

Answer (score 0):

In your example, notediv is already a jquery object:

```
function hideorshow(div){
if (div.is(':visible')) { //replace $(div) by div
    //hide if visible
    div.fadeOut();
} else {
        div.offset({top: posT-47});
        div.fadeIn();
}
};
```

Comment: not working same trouble, first works fine but then starts glitches